# Rendering an actor created within a vtkCommand (callback)

Tags: python, vtk

I am attempting to write a program that displays and cycles through images of different file formats when the arrow keys are pressed. I have found that setting up my reader->mapper->actor pipeline and then starting my RenderWindowInteractor allows the actor to be rendered, but moving this code to a callback for the RenderWindowInteractor's KeyPressEvent does not allow the actor to be rendered. Are there additional steps required to set up a new actor once the event loop has started, or have I made some other mistake?

```
import vtk

#Create the renderer that will display our actors
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()

actor = None

#Maps the data from the Nifti file 'filename' onto a vtkImageSlice actor
def LoadNifti():
    # load head MRI in NIFTI format
    reader = vtk.vtkNIFTIImageReader()
    reader.SetFileName("head.nii")
    reader.Update()

    # Add an ImageSliceMapper, which maps data to an ImageSlice Actor
    mapper = vtk.vtkImageSliceMapper()
    #Set the slice position to the camera focal point
    mapper.SliceAtFocalPointOn()
    mapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

    # Add an ImageSlice actor, which represents a slice as an image
    global actor
    actor = vtk.vtkImageSlice()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)

#Placeholder for when I have DICOM working
def ShowDICOM(filename):
    pass


#Create a RenderWindow to display images from the Renderer
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)

#Wrap the RenderWindow in a RenderWindowInteractor to catch key and mouse events
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

def foo():
    LoadNifti()
    ren.AddActor(actor)

##Extend the default functionality of the interactor and its style with custom listeners
def KeyPressEvent(obj, ev):
    foo()
    print("This verifies that the callback is triggered")
iren.AddObserver("KeyPressEvent", KeyPressEvent)        

#Start the program
###########################################################################
# WHEN foo() IS PRESENT BELOW, THE ACTOR WILL RENDER IMMEDIATELY.
# WHEN foo() IS ABSENT BELOW, CALLING foo() BY TRIGGERING THE KeyPressEvent
# IS NOT SUFFICIENT TO HAVE THE ACTOR RENDER.
###########################################################################
foo()
#According to the docs, the Start method will initialize iren and render renWin automatically
iren.Start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you definitely can add or remove actors inside a callback. To render the scene again immediately, simply call `iren.Render()`.

When you start a renderer without any visible actors and without an explicitly defined camera, then `ResetCamera` is typically required. Automatic `ResetCamera` is only called once during the initialization, and this is the reason, why calling `foo()` before `iren.Start()` makes the object visible.

```
def foo():
    LoadNifti()
    ren.AddActor(actor)
    ren.ResetCamera() # should that be necessary
    iren.Render()
```

Comment: vtkRenderer.ResetCamera() was 100% the method that I needed to be using. Thank you so much for your help - I'll pay it forward if I ever get the chance.