# How to update VTK renderWindow size and position in a callback?

Tags: python, render, vtk

I am trying to change and update a VTK renderWindow in callbacks (in Python) after it has been initially created, for example

```
... # Set up and initialize renderer
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)

iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

ren.AddActor(actor)

iren.Initialize()
renWin.Render()
iren.Start()

... # Callback
def my_cbf(x,y):
    renWin.Finalize()
    renWin.SetPosition(x,y)
    renWin.SetSize(640,480)
    renWin.Render()
```

does not really work in any permutation I can think of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering an actor created within a vtkCommand (callback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337397/rendering-an-actor-created-within-a-vtkcommand-callback)

Comment: @stovfl no, that doesn't seem to affect the actual render window

Comment: As it stands, you didn't call `def my_cbf(...`, this have to be done before `.Start()`.

Comment: Maybe its not so clear but after I have started the renderer I call the callback through some gui events which should resize the window, this is the issue. I can set the size before the initial start, but I guess it should be able to resize it?

Comment: ***" I call the callback through some gui events "***: So *callback* is not the right therm. Please confirm, your issue ist calling `def my_cbf(...` but the `.SetSize(640,480)` have no effect?